# network library with attributes fails: dims [product xx] do not match the length of object [x]

Tags: r, networking, attributes

I struggeling with loading a network `library(network)` with attributes.

In the following my subset of a dput:

```
 dput(edges[c(1:5,30:32),1:9])
structure(list(to = c(162L, 150L, 185L, 175L, 166L, 474L, 133L, 
206L), from = c(185L, 165L, 175L, 161L, 185L, 209L, 206L, 209L
), Year_n = c(1979, 1979, 1979, 1979, 1980, 1968, 1972, 1975), 
    iso3from = c("AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "BEN", "BEN", 
    "BEN"), iso3to = c("AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "AGO", "GAB", 
    "TGO", "BEN"), PLAN = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), length = c(255741.341008623, 
    374262.31750429, 242059.516330019, 284962.445273994, 340600.667130295, 
    1027620.84122649, 56431.0393784146, 37153.912532765), global = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), polityto = structure(c(-0.443128697523308, 
    -0.443128697523308, -0.443128697523308, -0.443128697523308, 
    -0.443128697523308, -0.833160613242787, -0.443128697523308, 
    -0.443128697523308), dim = c(8L, 1L))), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 30L, 31L, 32L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I run the code `network(edges, multiple = TRUE)` I get the the error: "dims [product xx] do not match the length of object [x]"
When I run `network(edges[,1:2], multiple = TRUE)` everything works as expected (but without attributes).
Looking for e.g. here, I would guess I follow the same attempt:
https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/network/html/loading.attributes.html

For completeness in the following my the traceback:

```
traceback()
8: lapply(.x, `attributes<-`, attributes(.x))
7: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
6: lapply(x, function(.x) {
       if (is.atomic(.x)) {
           lapply(.x, `attributes<-`, attributes(.x))
       }
       else {
           .x
       }
   })
5: .distribute_vec_attrs(edges[, edge_attr_names, drop = FALSE])
4: .prep_edge_attrs(x)
3: as.network.data.frame(x, directed = directed, hyper = hyper, 
       loops = loops, multiple = multiple, bipartite = bipartite, 
       ...)
2: as.network(x, directed = directed, hyper = hyper, loops = loops, 
       multiple = multiple, bipartite = bipartite, ...)
1: network(edges, multiple = TRUE)
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with that package, but `?network` says that its first argument should be a *"matrix giving the network structure in adjacency, incidence, or
edgelist form"*. My guess is that it is converting `edges[,1:2]` to a matrix which preserves the integer quality; when you pass more columns including `iso3*` which are strings, then when converting to a matrix, all of the numbers become strings. See `as.matrix(edges)` to see it in its corrupted form. If you need to include specific number-like columns, then include them specifically in your subset of `edges`.